# Кастомный контроллер на канве и взаимодействие с фрагментом

Tags: android

Доброго есть активити с разметкой:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <ru.planningtask.planningtime.ControllerTime
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </ru.planningtask.planningtime.ControllerTime>
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/fragment_text_time_controller"
        android:layout_width="50pt"
        android:layout_height="100pt">
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Как из кастомизированного  элемента  ru.planningtask.planningtime.ControllerTime динамически вставить фрагмент в FrameLayout?

Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Решил при помощи broadcastreceiver